# Want to create a NSMutableDictionary with the keys as integers and objects as strings in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I want to declare and initialize a NSMutableDictionary with a int:NSString combination.

I declared my mutable dictionary in a view controller header file as following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *gameDictionary;
```

And in viewDidLoad I initialized the dictionary:

```
gameDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

gameDictionary = @{@"1" : @"SquareOne", @"2" : @"SquareTwo", @"3" : @"SquareThree", @"4" : @"SquareFour", @"5" : @"SquareFive", @"6" : @"SquareSix", @"7" : @"SquareSeven", @"8" : @"SquareEight", @"9" : @"SquareNine"};
```

And in another method I tried to delete an object in the dictionary by giving its key:

```
[gameDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"1"];
```

But when I run the app I get an error: [__NSDictionaryI removeObjectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe79b5c97a0

I don't understand what I am doing wrong since the key is correct, so their must be something wrong with the way I am initializing it, can someone help me out?

Comment: `gameDictionary = @{...}` is an (immutable) `NSDictionary`. You need something like `gameDictionary = [@{...} mutableCopy]`, or set every key/value manually.

Comment: Ok thank you, now I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *gameDictionary = [@{@1 : @"SquareOne", @2 : @"SquareTwo", @3 : @"SquareThree", @4 : @"SquareFour", @5 : @"SquareFive", @6 : @"SquareSix", @7 : @"SquareSeven", @8 : @"SquareEight", @9 : @"SquareNine"} mutableCopy];
```

and

```
gameDictionary[@1] = nil;
```

Comment: Okay thank you. So can you please right the code to remove an object for key?

Comment: @Harsh.C: He showed you how to create an NSNumber object.That's all you need, turn an integer into an NSObject.

Comment: Yea I understand, that is why I put a question mark to indicate it is OK is he/she did not answer my question on the comment.